# Completely separate styles based on route - Vue

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-component

I'm currently using a UI Library in `main.js` for all routes, but I want certain routes to be completely isolated from the UI Library and to have custom styles. How do I achieve this?

- Using `<style scoped>` does not work because I need to work with the `body` tag.
- Using `<style>` does not work because if I visit the custom style route and go back to the normal route, styles from custom style route carry over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `<style scoped>` and for anything outside the scope of the component, use JS.

For example, if you only wanted the `body` to have a certain style for a certain route, you could add styles in the `created` hook and remove them in the `beforeDestroy` hook:

```
created() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.padding = "20rem";
},
beforeDestroy() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.padding = "0rem";
}
```

You could even create an entire stylesheet and append it to the `head`:

```
created() {
    const style = document.createElement("style");
    style.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    style.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    style.innerHTML = "body { padding: 20rem }";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);
},
beforeDestroy() {
    const head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    head.removeChild(head.children[head.childElementCount - 1]);
}
```

Just make sure you cleanup properly when navigating from the route as you could end up leaving the stylesheet behind if, for example, `head.children[head.childElementCount - 1]` doesn't return the stylesheet you appended.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to include more information in your post about what you've tried and what library you're using. You're more likely to get useful help that way